# How to insert a document to 2 collection in mongoose?

Tags: mongoose, collections, insert, updates

I have 2 collections( employee, hrmEployee)

employee schema is:

```
var EmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    code: String, //unique
    age : number,
    phoneNumber: number,
    });
```

hrmEmployee schema is:

```
var HrmEmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    name: String,
    code: String, //unique
    age : number,
    phoneNumber: number,
    address: String,
    startDateWork: date,
    organization : String
    });
```

hrmEmployee is collection expand the information of an employee. I want when creating an employee, the hrmEmployee will be created at the same time. Here is my solution:

```
var data ={
name: "test001",
code: "A01",
age : 20,
phoneNumber : 123123123
}

var employee = new Employee(data);
    employee
    .save()
  .then( result => {
    if(result){
    var hrmEmployee = new HrmEmployee(data)
            hrmEmployee.save()
    }
  }).catch( err => console.log(err))
```

Does anyone have a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use async await syntax for better code readability

```
async function saveEmployee() {
  try {
     const data = {
      name: "test001",
      code: "A01",
      age : 20,
      phoneNumber : 123123123
    };
    
    const employee = new Employee(data);
    await employee.save();

    const hrmEmployee = new HrmEmployee(data)
    await hrmEmployee.save();

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Also, duplicating same information in two different documents is not ideal since you will have to always keep the two documents in sync when updating info. A better way would be to reference employee document id in hrmEmployee schema and add just additional fields in hrmEmployee

```
var HrmEmployeeSchema = new Schema({
    employeeId: {
      type: ObjectId,
      ref: "Employee"
    },
    address: String,
    startDateWork: date,
    organization : String
 });
```

That said, if you want to ensure that both documents are always created you should consider using Mongodb Transaction which ensures atomicity across collections. You can read more about transactions here -
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/transactions/